# Configure postfix to view catch-all address in mail header

Tags: linux, centos, postfix-mta, dovecot

I configured catchall for postfix as follows:-

> "#vim /etc/postfix/virtual
>
> @example.com  test"

So if we send mail to  xyzjsdv@example.com will get delivered to test@example.com.

But the problem was it always shows the same user name in the mail header "test@example.com". I created a script for checking the mail header, so that I need the particular user@example should be display at the mail header since I need to differentiate all the users.

Please help me how to configure the postfix, so that I will get this outcome. Sudden answers would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer - but some questions as I have no rep I can't put comments on.

What version of postfix are you running?

I'm doing a similar thing on 2.8, and it is working as expected, ie: the message itself (not the "envelope") has the correct headers - ie: the message is unmodified.

What test message are you sending? I would suggest testing with something simple, using telnet run the following, eg:

```
telnet <server> 25
Connected to <server>.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.example.com ESMTP
helo test.com
250 nbb-dev.safenetbox.biz
mail from:<somewhere@example.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: <def@example.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Sender: abc@example.com
Subject: testing

body
.
quit
```

For me this gives the "letter" message with the sender as "abc@example.com".

Also ensure there are no *header_rewrite* settings, except defaults (I have never used these, but could be related).

How are you getting the message, from a mailbox, or is it getting sent to a program directly? If going to a mailbox, is it getting forwarded?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question; mostly, you are asking for clarification. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Correct, as you say, I can't ask for clarification (via a comment which is what I tried) until I have enough reputation, so I can't answer a question, to get reputation - you see the dilemma I'm sure... (I have updated the answer to clarify this).

Comment: You can answer questions you know how to answer, and if your answers are good then you will get upvotes. But you shouldn't post an "answer" that doesn't answer the question. That will get deleted eventually and may get downvoted, as well, which costs you reputation and could get you banned.